# Loading bar while submitting jquery ajax post, don't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, loading

I'm using [jQuery UI dialog modal form](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

All works great, but I send an ajax post, so I added this code:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 550,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create an account": function() {

                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                    if ( bValid ) {
                            $.ajax({ url: 'about.php',
                                 data: {name: name.val(), email: email.val()},
                             type: 'post',
                             async: false
                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

The `$.ajax` part is what I added.
I want to show a Loading bar while processing the post, I added this code:

```
$('#progress')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

But it doesn't work, my post goes to a php script which one have 2 seconds waiting time.
It just don't show the `#progress div`, so the `.hide` is working.

Also, for example if I add `$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({ hide: "slide" });` before the `$.ajax` it doesn't work, it hides once all button function is finished.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `#progress div` is only show during this ajax call, why don't you put the `show`/`hide` action on your button action ?

Like this :

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Create an account": function() {

                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                if ( bValid ) {
                        // show before ajax call
                        $('#progress').show();

                        $.ajax({ url: 'about.php',
                             data: {name: name.val(), email: email.val()},
                             type: 'post',
                             async: true,
                             complete: function() {
                                 //hide on complete
                                 $('#progress').hide();
                             }
                     });
              }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Don't work. $('#progress').show(); don't work. No matter what I write before ajax or after it just don't work until all is done on the main function buttons: {"Create an account": function()

Comment: @QuiGloriam try to change `async: false` to `async: true` in your ajax call.